# Odoo 13 - Search method - use of 'order' attribute for the model's related fields

Tags: python, orm, odoo, odoo-13

I have 2 models more like the example below

**Model 1 - invoice**

```
invoice_num = fields.Char(String='Invoice Number')
payment_method = fields.Char(String='Payment Method')
payment_date = fields.Datetime(String='Invoice Payment Date')
paid_by_id = fields.Many2one('user_details', String='Paid by user ID')
.
.
.
```

**Model 2 - user_details**

```
first_name = fields.Char(String='First Name')
last_name = fields.Char(String='Last Name')
age = fields.Integer()
.
.
.
```

I am trying to fetch all the records from the invoice model with the following search conditions

**Domain filters** - payment_method = 'Cash' & paid_by_id.age > 25

**Order** - paid_by_id.first_name desc

**Offset** - 200

**Limit** - 10

For the above, the raw query would be like

```
SELECT * FROM invoice inv
JOIN user_details ud ON inv.paid_by_id = ud.id
WHERE inv.payment_method = 'Cash' and ud.age > 25
ORDER BY ud.first_name
OFFSET 200 LIMIT 10;
```

I tried to write ORM for the same like

```
records = request.env['invoice'].sudo().search([('payment_method', '=', 'Cash'), ('paid_by_id.age', '>', 25)], order='paid_by_id.first_name desc', offset=200, limit=10)
```

But, I get the below error-

```
'Invalid "order" specified. A valid "order" specification is a comma-separated list of valid field names (optionally followed by asc/desc for the direction)'
```

So, how to fetch records using 'order' attribute for the model's related fields?

Comment: Interesting question! But yeah, Odoo is really strict on the content of the `order` parameter. If you want to get an answer to your "extended" question (info in your comment under the answer), you should ask another one. But i bet the answers are: use a stored related/computed field or use a query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [order](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/13.0/odoo/models.py#L4381) must be a comma-separated list of valid field names, optionally followed by an `ASC` or `DESC` direction.

You can't use dotted names (fields of relational fields).

Comment: Thank you for the response. I want to avoid fetching all the records (say 50000 rows) from the DB and do operations on it. Because, as you can see, (For pagination purpose) I am using 'offset' and 'limit' attributes to fetch only limited number of rows. 

So, the sorting and offset should happen while fetching the records. If I use sorted function on the fetched record set, I will not get the expected list of records as some records are skipped already using offset & limit.

Comment: Sorry, I did not take in consideration offset and order, I updated my answer

Comment: Try to use permanent links to code, because it can change over time, and always try to "copy" the important part of that code into your answer because it could vanish.

Comment: @DipenShah The important part is the doc string and I already copied it. The validation is done is the `_generate_order_by_inner` method and exactly in `_check_qorder` when they try to match the order string.